# Spring Batch 4 creating of TransactionManager prevents JPA TransactionManager creation

Tags: spring-batch

As stated here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/816, use of BatchConfigurer bean makes some obstacles for JPA, this behaviour was fixed in Spring Batch 5, but the problem is that I use spring-boot 2.7.10, while Spring Batch 5 requires 3+, are there any workarounds to make JPA work again in Spring Batch 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not share your code, so I will guess.

With Spring Batch 4 / Spring Boot 2, you need to define a custom `BatchConfigurer` bean to return the `JpaTransactionManager` from `BatchConfigurer#getTransactionManager` and use `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`.